# How to call Azure Durable Functions with Web hook with Azure Data Factory? -Timeout occurs

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-durable-functions

I have done Durable Function Python tutorial and deployed to Azure Functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

I have succesfully tested triggering Function by http://.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/HelloOrchestrator

How to trigger with Azure Data Factory?

1. I tried to add "Web Hook" activity from Azure Data Factory
2. Url is : https://durablefunctionappxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/HelloOrchestrator
3. Methos is set POST
4. Body {}
5. Triggered succesfully
6. Pipeline Runs says duration 8:36 and status "in progress".
7. Pipeline Runs finally gives error on 10:03 "Operation on target Durable WebHook1 failed: Activity timed out"
8. I see no activity in Activity Log of Azure Functions

Please advice me how to trigger durable functions.
I would like to get some status info back as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call durable function using "Azure Function" activity by passing Orchestrator function name to the activity. Considering your sample function application as an example, you need to pass function name like below to start the Orchestrator.
[image]

This Activity will return a response with different URI's like **statusQueryGetUri** once the orchestration is successfully started. (See Screenshot below)
[image]

Now, in order to call any specific endpoint like **statusQueryGetUri**, you can then add a **Web Activity** with by passing the url received from earlier activity like below -
`@activity('<AzureFunctionActivityName>').output.statusQueryGetUri`

[image]

When pipeline is executed successfully you should be able to get the results as the output of the Web Activity.
[image]

Reference documentation - [Azure Function activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity#timeout-and-long-running-functions)